# Validation of setModel()?

Tags: java, swing

In Netbeans, I have this code to fill a JTable.

```
public void fillTable() {
    String col[] = {"Username", "Mail", "Birthday"};

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);

    for (User u : this.uc.getL()) {
        String birthday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(u.getBirthday());
        Object[] data = {u.getUsername(), u.getMail(), birthday};
        tableModel.addRow(data);
    }
    this.userTable.setModel(tableModel);
}
```

After looking around for any guidance on this issue, I continue to have this blank table.

What could I be doing wrong?

Here the main class

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaApplication5 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Frame.main(args);

}

}
```

Here the frame with the JTable.

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;  
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;  
import javax.swing.JTable;  
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;  

public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Frame
 */
public Frame() {
    this.fillTable();
    initComponents();
}

public void fillTable() {
    String col[] = {"Username", "Mail", "Birthday"};

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(col, 0);

    Object[] data = {"MrTest", "Mr@Test.com", "22/10/1985"};
    tableModel.addRow(data);
    Object[] data2 = {"MrsTest", "Mrs@Test.com", "13/05/1987"};
    tableModel.addRow(data2);
    userTable = new JTable(tableModel);
    this.jsUser = new JScrollPane(userTable);
    this.jsUser.setVisible(true);
    this.userTable.setVisible(true);
    userTable.setModel(tableModel);
}


// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    lUser = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jsUser = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    userTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lUser.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    lUser.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lUser.setText("test Jtable");
    getContentPane().add(lUser, java.awt.BorderLayout.NORTH);

    userTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Username", "Mail", "Birthday"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jsUser.setViewportView(userTable);

    getContentPane().add(jsUser, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Frame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jsUser;
private javax.swing.JLabel lUser;
private javax.swing.JTable userTable;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

---

**RESOLUTION:**

For the people who searched to understand, I would like to say I resolved my problem.

This one was in two parts: where the model come from and the existence of the model itself.

The first problem was resolved when I understood Netbeans had specificities. In effect, the GUI generated a model you could modify. But to use it, you shoud create the DefaultTableModel with it in head. So my function now look like this.

```
  public void fillTable() {

    DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) userTable.getModel();

    for (User u : this.uc.getL()) {
        String birthday = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(u.getBirthday());

        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{u.getUsername(), u.getMail(), birthday});
    }
}
```

The second part was more simple then. I tested the existence of the columns of the table. There was none. And there I understood another thing : The table should be done in the function initComponents, then the function to populate it should be done after, like this :

```
  public userAdmin() {
    this.userTable = new JTable();
    this.uc = new userController();
    this.uc.setuA(this);
    initComponents();
    this.fillTable();
}
```

Now it works.

Comment: Recommend posing a [mcve]

Comment: I would guess your "for loop" doesn't execute because there are no users. Did you do any basic debugging to check this?

Comment: Yes. I tested the content of the jtable with
System.out.println(userTable.getModel().getRowCount());
After the setModel. I have my two users.

I also verified the content of the row with 
System.out.println(userTable.getModel().getValueAt(1, 2));
The birthday date is there.

Comment: Then the table you add to the frame is not the table you update in your method. We are not mind readers.We can't guess what your code is doing.  Until you post your  `MCVE` we can't help.

Comment: Agree with camickr here. You are creating a `this.userTable = new JTable();` in the constructor, and there is another `userTable = new javax.swing.JTable();` dubiously floating in the (horribly formatted) code. *Where* exactly do you add *which* table to some top-level component?

Comment: @Fhurai, how is that an `MCVE`? How is the code complete? How can we compile and test it?

Comment: There you have the panel and its controller. It should permit you to test it.

Comment: @Marco13, how do you expect us to execute that code? We don't have access to your database. The point of the `MCVE` is to simplify the code so that you understand how it works. So first create a simple example that add hard coded data to you table. Then once you understand how this works, you add back in the logic to make the adding of rows dynamic.

Comment: Here i put all in two files, without use of user object. You have two Object with the wanted data. You have yje DefaultTableModel with the wanted columns. A,d I all tested, it's like I have in my true project. Sorry but there I will go, it"s late by home.

Comment: @camickr That should probably have been @ the asker...